# Calculating Sum of a particular field and display it at the end in Crystal Report

Tags: c#, visual-studio, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I am new to crystal report. What is want is to display the total sum of a particular item, my report is like this

```
-----------------------------------
    Used By     --   Item   --- qty
     Honda City     
                    Petrol  --- 20
                    Oil     --- 10
    ----------------------------------
    M Lancer 
                    Petrol  ---- 5
                    TF Oil  ---- 2
   -----------------------------------
   Summary 
       Petrol : 25
       Oil    : 10
       TF Oil :  2
 --------------------------------------
```

Like this my report. but how I can calculate the sum of each Item and show at the end of the report?If total 10 pages are there, I want it to be showed at 10th page. Thanks in Advance. Harie

Answer (score 0):

If qty is a single column, then you can create conditional subtotals by inserting Running Totals.  See the Evaluate section, there is an option to Use a formula.  The subtotal fields can then by put in in your Report Footer region to make them appear at the end of the report. Here is the basic syntax for the formula, a sample for a Petrol total.

Item = "Petrol"